# why DMARC policy detected as not enabled

Tags: email, dns, dmarc

I dont know why, when I test my domain via mxtoolbox this week I got result DMARC policy is not enabled.
This is not happened before, everything is ok and I never do any changes in my DNS server.
[image]

I checked my DNS record and there is no issue, my DMARC policy set to quarantine.

```
_dmarc.mydomain.com.    IN  TXT "v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; pct=100; ruf=mailto:admin@mydomain.com; rua=mailto:admin@mydomain.com; sp=none; adkim=s; aspf=s"
```

How to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Which DMARC validator are you using, and what's your TTL?

Comment: This website says your DMARC policy is valid: https://vamsoft.com/support/tools/dmarc-policy-validator

Comment: I use mxtoolbox.com , as shown in my picture above. it is show dmarc policy is not enabled

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it refers to your subdomain policy (`sp`). With your current DMARC record, I could simply send (i.e. spoof) emails from subdomain.mydomain.com instead of mydomain.com. Remove `sp=none;` so that subdomains inherit the policy of your organizational domain.